# Insert id retrieving data from different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, insert

I have a Table A with customers and a Table P with products.

I also have a table C which represents the purchased product by customers.

The table fields are as follow:

A (Customers)

```
user_id
Name
Surname
```

P (Products)

```
product_id
price
product name
```

C (Purchased products)

```
id
product_id
user_id
quantity 
date
```

C is the many-to-many link between A and P.

Assume that today a customer named "Bob Wright" has bought a product called "Beautiful_magazine". Assume that both customer and product are already in the database.

How do I make the entry in the C table?

I know that I should use the insert into select statement but I am facing hard time because I should retrieve the user id form A and the product id form P and then placing them into a new line in C along with the function NOW() and a numerical values representing the price.
I cannot do that because I am a newbie.

Any hint?

EDIT
I would like to make it manually, using the INSERT statement without relying on the software.

Assume:

user_id: 890
Name: Bob 
Surname: Wright

product_id: 4897
price: 5.90
product_name: Beautiful_magazine

I need to create a new line in C table as follow:

id (autoincremental)
product_id: 4897
user_id: 890
quantity: 1 
date: '2017-2-20'

Obviously, the product_id and user_id from P and A should be retrieve through a select statement using the where statement.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Add sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: `I should retrieve the user id form A and the product id form P ` - Usually it's available in the code that will create the "purchase" entry... so you will need to show us the code that surround that also...

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the data in from an application, use a [procedure](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843) (assuming that the id auto increments)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddSale` (IN ProdID INT, IN UserID INT, IN Qty INT)
BEGIN
  insert into TableC (Product_ID, User_ID, Quantity, Date)
  values (ProdID, UserID, Qty, Now());

END
```

In your application, call the procedure and passin the parameters